# Assign Multiple Dates per Student ID

Tags: r

I have a list of student ids, listed 1-30 or student_id=c(1:30). How can I now assign a date from 01-01-2019 to today, to each student using either R base package or dplyr functions. The desired out would be something like:

```
 Student_ID Date 
  1          01-01-2019
  1          01-02-2019
  1          01-03-2019
  1          01-04-2019 
  2          01-01-2019
  2          01-02-2019
  2          01-03-2019
  2          01-04-2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe for students list and for Date list, and merge them without any key -

```
s<-data.frame(student_id=c(1:30))
d<-data.frame(date=seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by = 'days'))
merge(s,d, all=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try generating a sequence of dates and then repeating the sequence as necessary.  For your example, assuming your data.frame is called `students`

```
date <- seq(as.Date("01012019",format="%d%m%Y"),as.Date("04012019",format="%d%m%Y"),by=1)

students$Date <- rep(date, times = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `ave` for a running count by group that you can use to add to the start date, 2019-01-01. This adjusts to any size grouping by *Student_ID*:

```
df$Date <- with(df, ave(Student_ID, Student_ID, FUN=seq_along)-1 + as.Date("2019-01-01"))

df    
#   Student_ID       Date
# 1          1 2019-01-01
# 2          1 2019-01-02
# 3          1 2019-01-03
# 4          1 2019-01-04
# 5          2 2019-01-01
# 6          2 2019-01-02
# 7          2 2019-01-03
# 8          2 2019-01-04
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/VEUD48067)